# cordova-plugin-inappbrowser for ios Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 5.1.1, failed version requirement: >=6.0.0

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, google-plus, inappbrowser

My issue is I keep getting rejected by the Apple store for having UIWeb in my plugins.  So I've upgraded all of my plugins but my issue is Google Plus won't install with cordova-ios 6.x.  I can only get Google Plus installed with cordova-ios 5.1.1.  The conflict is that cordova inapp browser won't install on 5.1.1, it needs 6.x or greater.  I'm not sure how to resolve this issue with two different cordova plugins requiring different cordova-ios versions.

Is there an alternative to inapp browser?

Is there a way to open browser links from ionic without inapp browser?

```
"cordova-ios": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^5.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
```

Comment: What plugin do you use for google plus ?

Comment: "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",

Comment: "cordova-ios": "^6.0.0",

Comment: It appears this plugin is not compatible with ios 6+ https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/720

Comment: @Eric i know.  But inAppBrowser fails with 5.1.1

Comment: I have no issues with cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@4.1.0 + ios 6+

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, yes there is. You can open links in the user's default browser using `window.open` as follows:

> window.open('https://www.andreszsogon.com/', '_system');

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only solution I could find for this scenario was to cave to the demands of InAppBrowser.

You start by removing your existing iOS platform:

```sh
ionic cordova platforms remove ios
```

You then install ios@6.0.0, specifically:

```sh
ionic cordova platforms add ios@6.0.0
```

As a bonus side-note, if you are using Stripe you may encounter a bug where Stripe keeps popping up on app launch, that's apparently, allegedly [due to spying](https://mtlynch.io/stripe-recording-its-customers/).